# Open link in one WebView to another Webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview

I'm developing a app in Xcode with a tab bar which has two webviews. I need to make certain links in WebView 1, the tab called "Författare" (I'm gonna go ahead and call the webviews by numbers) go straight to certain parts of a HTML picture gallery in WebView 2 "Utställningar" with the correct tab being selected while doing so. How would I connect the two?
I have the HTML links between the two different local HTML files but how can I make sure that the correct tab is selected (WebView 2) when the link is clicked in WebView 1? I hope I'm making enough sense!

Answer (score 0):

Implement the UIWebViewDelegate method: webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

Inside this method, you can examine the request.URL, and make your decision about which tab to select based on that.